# upload media to GoJS diagram with nodes through jQuery ajax Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, gojs

### Hello guys,

im making a web page which **provides a node diagram** and every node should have one **media**(photo, video, sound, text) on it. I use the javascript library [GoJs](http://gojs.net/latest/learn/index.html) to make the node diagram but i'm having a problem in how to bind in every node with the uploaded media(the media is uploaded by the user with the Ajax form).

Does anyone have an idea in how to make this work?

by the way the media uploader works fine.

#### Here is my js code for the node diagram so far:

```
 // define the Node template for nodes
myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Auto",  // the whole node panel
      new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),{
      // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the TextBlock
              resizable: true, 
              resizeObjectName: "RRectangle", 
              resizeCellSize: new go.Size(10, 10),
              selectionObjectName: "SHAPE" 
              },
          
        
        $(go.Picture, {                                             //main image for all nodes
             source: "images/nodeicon.png", 
             background: "#E67E22",
             width: 65,
             height: 65,
             maxSize: new go.Size(50, 50),
             margin: new go.Margin(0), 
             },
            new go.Binding("source")),
                         
    
            )
    );


// This converter is used by the mediaUploader
    function mediaContent(mediaC) {
        use some SetDataProperty(data,source,mediaC)
      ..
    };
```

> the mediaContent function returns the php echo's.
>
> e.g.  '/media/IMG_4310.jpg'

#### Media uploader method: Ajax form

```
//------                                //
//          MEDIA UPLOAD                //
//------                                //
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
            beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
            success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
            uploadProgress: OnProgress, //upload progress callback 
            resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
        }; 
...
```

#### and some part of the php media uploader:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName ))
   {
    if($File_Ext=='.jpg' || $File_Ext=='.jpg' || $File_Ext=='.png' || $File_Ext=='.gif' )
    {
        //echo "<img src='media/".$NewFileName."' id='preview' class='img-responsive'>";
        echo 'media/'.$NewFileName.'';
    }

}
else{
    die('error uploading File!');
}
```

Comment: What's not working in the JavaScript, exactly?

Comment: there is no error in javaScript. The Problem was in how to do combine the GoJs with the media. Btw i found it. So now it does!